# How can I SUM values based om multiple criteria where one is a range (list of values)?

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, sumproduct

I am using Google Sheets, but it looks like nowadays it supports most of Excel functions as well.

I want to get SUM based on multiple criteria. I have found formulas for each criterion, but I have not found any way to combine those criteria.

[image: Example image of what I achieved]

`SUM of all values (G) where E="X"
 - SUMIFS(G3:G9;E3:E9;"X")`

`SUM of all values (G) where F is in B
 - SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(F3:F9;B3:B7;G3:G9))`

**What formula can I use?**

`SUM of all values (G) where F is in B AND E="X"
 - ??`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
=sumproduct(isnumber(match(F3:F9,B3:B7,0)),(E3:E9="X"),G3:G9)
```

---

**A brief explanation**

`isnumber(match(F3:F9,B3:B7,0))` ceates a column of true (1s) and false (0s) values if the value in column F is found in column B.

`(E3:E9="X")` does the same thing if column E has the value X

`sumproduct()`: and where both the above are true (1s), these get multiplied by the corresponding value in G and the whole column is added up. If either is zero, the corresponding value is zero, of course.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(QUERY(E2:G, "where E='X' and F='B'", 0))
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=SUMPRODUCT(QUERY(E2:G, "where not F matches 'F|G|H|I' and E='X' or F='B'", 0))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Very elegant use of the `Query` function. If I may make a tweak to drop the `sumproduct` and avoid the hardcoded match values: `=index(QUERY(E3:G, "Select sum(G) where E='X' and F matches '"&TEXTJOIN("|",1,B3:B)&"'", 0),2)`